# postgresql syntax error at or near create when creating a function

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a function in postgresql,
Some functions work and other genertes an error,
The code is:

```
 Create or replace function CalcScore(Drive_name varchar,FromPlanet varchar, ToPlanet varchar)  returns integer as $$
    declare
        driverLoc Locations%ROWTYPE;
        fromLoc Locations%ROWTYPE;
        toLoc Locations%ROWTYPE;
        plantDist integer;
        driverDist integer;
    begin
    SELECT * FROM Location INTO driverLoc
    WHERE Name=Drive_name;
    SELECT * FROM Location INTO fromLoc
    WHERE Name=FromPlanet;
    SELECT * FROM Location INTO toLoc
    WHERE Name=ToPlanet;
    plantDist :=floor(sqrt(
            (fromLoc.X - toLoc.X)*(fromLoc.X - toLoc.X) + 
            (fromLoc.Y - toLoc.Y)*(fromLoc.Y - toLoc.Y)+
            (fromLoc.Z - toLoc.Z)*(fromLoc.Z - toLoc.Z)
            ));
    driverDist :=floor(sqrt(
            (fromLoc.X - driverLoc.X)*(fromLoc.X - driverLoc.X) + 
            (fromLoc.Y - driverLoc.Y)*(fromLoc.Y - driverLoc.Y)+
            (fromLoc.Z - driverLoc.Z)*(fromLoc.Z - driverLoc.Z)
            ));
    return planetDist-DriverDist;
    end;
    $$language plpgsql;
```

The error I get is:

```
57: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Create"
LINE 25: Create or replace function CalcScore(Drive_name varchar,From...
```

I get error for other functions as well.
The Table 'Location' exist, any idea?

Comment: Variable declarations use `Locations%ROWTYPE` (location**s** - with "s" at the end), while `SELECT * FROM Location INTO` statements reference Location table (without "s").

Comment: Another error: `return planetDist-DriverDist;` references `Plan**e**tDist` while declaration says `plantDist integer;` (without "e")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in this code:

Variable declarations use `Locations%ROWTYPE` (location**s** - with "s"
   at the end), 
while `SELECT * FROM Location INTO` statements reference
   `Location` table (without "s").
 
`return planetDist-DriverDist;`
   references `Plan**e**tDist`
 while declaration says `plantDist integer;`
   (without "e")

After fixing these two errors the function compiles and works fine,
 see this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/38d68/1

```
Create or replace function CalcScore(Drive_name varchar,FromPlanet varchar, ToPlanet varchar)  returns integer as $$
    declare
        driverLoc Locations%ROWTYPE;
        fromLoc Locations%ROWTYPE;
        toLoc Locations%ROWTYPE;
        plantDist integer;
        driverDist integer;
    begin
    SELECT * FROM Locations INTO driverLoc
    WHERE Name=Drive_name;
    SELECT * FROM Locations INTO fromLoc
    WHERE Name=FromPlanet;
    SELECT * FROM Locations INTO toLoc
    WHERE Name=ToPlanet;
    plantDist :=floor(sqrt(
            (fromLoc.X - toLoc.X)*(fromLoc.X - toLoc.X) + 
            (fromLoc.Y - toLoc.Y)*(fromLoc.Y - toLoc.Y)+
            (fromLoc.Z - toLoc.Z)*(fromLoc.Z - toLoc.Z)
            ));
    driverDist :=floor(sqrt(
            (fromLoc.X - driverLoc.X)*(fromLoc.X - driverLoc.X) + 
            (fromLoc.Y - driverLoc.Y)*(fromLoc.Y - driverLoc.Y)+
            (fromLoc.Z - driverLoc.Z)*(fromLoc.Z - driverLoc.Z)
            ));
    return plantDist-DriverDist;
    end;
    $$language plpgsql/
```